How to Extend Existing Types with Methods in Lua, Similar to Swift Extensions or JavaScript Prototypes?
In Swift, you can add methods to existing types using extensions, and in JavaScript, you can do the same using prototypes. How can I achieve a similar functionality in Lua?
I want to add a clamp function to numbers.
If this is not possible, please let me know.

From Lua, if the debug library is available, you can use debug.getmetatable and debug.setmetatable to change the metatables for non table types.
As with any metatable, the __index metamethod can be used to make the object respond to key indexing.
A cursory example. Note that in debug.getmetatable(0) and debug.setmetatable(0, mt), 0 is a chosen as an arbitrary number value. Passing any number value to these functions will work to access the metatable for the type.
local mt = debug.getmetatable(0) or {}
local methods = {}
mt.__index = methods 

function methods:clamp(lower, upper)
    if lower > self then return lower end
    if upper < self then return upper end
    return self
end

debug.setmetatable(0, mt)

for i = 1, 5 do 
    local n = math.random(100)
    print(n, n:clamp(33, 66))
end 

88  66
48  48
46  46
20  33
70  66


See Lua 5.4: 2.1 - Values and Types | 2.4 – Metatables and Metamethods | 6.10 – The Debug Library 

upvoted: It worked. Why are you using 0 with getmetatable and setmetatable? There was no description of numbers in the documentation. debug.getmetatable(value): Returns the metatable of the given value or nil if it does not have a metatable. If it would be better as a separate question, I can create a new one.

0 is an arbitrary value - we just need to pass any number to getmetatable/setmetatable to access the type's metatable. I'll add this information to the answer.

The idea is that this time we want to extend number, so any instance of number should be fine, right? (I'm not sure if "instance" is the correct term in Lua)

Yes, exactly. The same logic applies to strings, functions, light userdata, booleans, and even nil.
